# Performance of: if (OBJECT_INSTANCE is TYPE)

Tags: c#, actionscript-3

I am working both in C# and ActionScript 3. Both languages are type-aware, so you can do verifications such as:

```
if (some_object_instance is SomeClassName_ThatIs_SomeType)
```

I'm doing these kind of verifications in a few places. Might be a dumb question, but I will ask it anyway, and I want answers from both camps, C# and ActionScript:

What goes on behind the scenes? Is it Reflection? If is, isn't this a long verification which might degrade performance if done in thousands of loops? And by "degrade performance" I mean, is it more intensive than say if `(Math.sqrt(8) > Math.sin(10))`

Comment: It's probably not reflection, at least not for C#. I'm also sure performance is not a matter in C#. I can't say much for the Flash Player (or AIR) however.

Comment: Even if it is "slow" - have you an alternative? If it is "slow" - will you avoid of using it?

Comment: I'd venture that one can use OOP techniques to avoid having to make type checks. There are usually neater ways/patterns by which one can achieve type specific behaviours.

Comment: You're probably right spender, but some situations do require type checking and cannot be "polymorphisized" away (yeah, I made that word up).  That said, why don't you just use ILDASM and see what IL is generated?

Comment: zerkms: this is for my sleep quality ::- D. spender: it's true, but the question is: do I need to over-design if this is a non-issue?

Comment: @Axonn - I can't speak for actionscript, but in C# your "over-design" is likely to be slower than [isinst](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.isinst.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's reflection and it's not. An "is" statement will cause the runtime to examine the manifest of the assembly containing the type, to inspect the inheritance hierarchy. Programmatic reflection would do the same thing. However, in this case it's done using a far more lightweight and specific means built into the runtime than would be available from the System.Reflection namespace.

Answer (score 4):

In C# (or better put: ILCode), it is compiled to an instruction. Good read for that [Is is as or is as is? by Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/16/is-is-as-or-is-as-is.aspx).

Comment: was too lazy to google for that topic and waited until someone have posted it ;-) +1